# Lower bounded parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, bounded-types

I'm fairly new to TypeScript so I may well just be doing something stupid but I've found what appears to be either a bug or a limitation. I have defined an interface for a function that takes a `Foo`. If I give that function to another function, the contract would seem to be that the function I pass must take **any** `Foo`. However, if I define `class Bar extends Foo` and then a function that takes a `Bar`, but not a `Foo`, I can pass that to a function that requires a function taking any `Foo`. Example:

```
class Foo {

}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

interface TakesAnyFoo {
    (x: Foo) : void;
}

function needsAFunctionThatTakesAnyFoo(f: TakesAnyFoo) {
    let foo = new Foo();
    f(foo);
}

function takesOnlyABar(x: Bar) {
    console.log(`I got ${x}`);
}

needsAFunctionThatTakesAnyFoo(takesOnlyABar);
```

I think maybe what I need here is the equivalent of Java's lower bounded types. Something like:

```
interface TakesAnyFoo<T super Foo> {
    (x: T) : void;
}
```

but Typescript doesn't appear to have this. How can I enforce a constraint that the function passed to `needsAFunctionThatTakesAnyFoo` must accept any `Foo` as its input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your code we have :

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}

function needsAFunctionThatTakesAnyFoo(f: (x: Foo) => void) {
    let foo = new Foo();
    f(foo);
}

needsAFunctionThatTakesAnyFoo((x: Bar) => { });
```

This is supported to allow the common pattern in event handlers. e.g. Giving a function that takes a `MouseEvent` to an event specification that only supports `Event`.

## More

This is covered here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Type%20Compatibility.md#comparing-two-functions

Comment: Thanks. Disappointing design decision IMHO but that's certainly not your fault.